# filemode missing from python os.stat ? MacOS

Tags: python

I am clearly missing something here. I've tried this in V3.7, 3.9 and 3.10. All get the error.

```
import  sys
from    os  import stat

print(f"Python Version {sys.version.split()[0]}")

filename = '/Users/Shared/Apps/Testing/Logs/Database/PostgresPythonLibrary.log'
print(stat(filename).st_mode)
print(stat.filemode(stat(filename).st_mode))
```

Output:

```
Python Version 3.10.2
33204
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python/Projects/Test/post.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(stat.filemode(stat(filename).st_mode))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'filemode'
```

MacOS 12.0.1 (Monterey)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the function `stat` in the os module with the module `stat` (yes it's bad naming. It's a side effect of how the features were added historically).

You'd need to do something like

```py
import os
import stat

filename = foo

print(stat.filemode(os.stat(filename).st_mode))
```

Comment: Bad naming indeed.